# How do I enable/disable an input textbox when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I mapped a list of dependents which was fetched from an API. Each dependent has a corresponding checkbox and input box.

```
const [depInput, setDepInput]= useState({disable:"true", checked:"false"});
  


<div>
 {items.dependents?.map((item, key) => {
                return (
                  
                    <p key={key}> Name: {item.name} </p>
                    <div>
                      <input 
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={!depInput.checked}
                      onChange={() => setDepInput(!depInput.disable)}
                      disable={!depInput.disable} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input type="text"
                       
                       placeholder="Enter correct detail"
                       disabled={!depInput.disable}
                       onChange={() => setDepInput(!depInput.checked)} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <select defaultValue={item.type_of_dependent}>
                        <option>Primary</option>
                        <option>Secondary</option>
                        <option> NA</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </>
                );
              })}
</div>
```

When I click the checkbox of the first dependent, it disables the other input textboxes. I intend to have each checkbox and corresponding input text box have a toggle state.

Comment: You're setting the value of `depInput` to a boolean in the `onChange` methods.

Comment: The name of the property is `disabled`, not `disable`.

Comment: You only have one state variable for all of your `item`s. You'd need one for each `item`. I suggest adding a component for the checkbox and input (at least) and setting up the `useState` in that component.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a demo for you it should help you out. What you need is separate state for each checkbox. I have added comments let me know if this helps you
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-northcutt-growt?file=/src/App.js